# Does $(6-\sqrt{37})y^2=(6-\sqrt{37})^2-68x^4$ have solution over $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{37})=\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$ and over $\Bbb{Q}_{17}(\sqrt{37})$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the equation
$$(6-\sqrt{37})y^2=(6-\sqrt{37})^2-68x^4
$$
over $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{37})=\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$ and over $\Bbb{Q}_{17}(\sqrt{37})$.

I guess from computational caluculation that it does not have solution over either $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$ or $\Bbb{Q}_{17}(\sqrt{37})$.
But I'm unable to prove that by hand. It seems extremely difficult for me.

For example, suppose the equation has a solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$. Taking the 2-adic valuation $v$ gives $2v(y)=\min\{0,2+4v(x)\}$. But I couldn't find any contradiction.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is incorrect to say $v(a+b) = \min(v(a),v(b))$ for all $a$ and $b$. That would be true when $v(a)\not=v(b)$, but it need not be true otherwise. In general, $v(a+b)\geq\min(v(a),v(b))$.

Comment: In the relevant $2$-adic extension we can render elements as $a+b\omega$, where $\omega^3=1$ and $a,b$
 are $2$-adic integers. Then $v(a+b,\omega)=\min[v(a),v(b)]$.

Comment: @KCd. But $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})/\Bbb{Q}_2$ is unratified, thus $v(x)$ is integer. $0=2+4v(x)$ cannot happen in this situation.

Comment: "Unratified". Do we need a Republican Senate to get the votes?  You may have meant "unra**m**ified".

Comment: Sorry, 'unramified'.